# How do you determine DC polarity when the device does not specify?

Tags: power, desktop-computer

My device is the [ASRock Vision 3D Series](https://www.asrock.com/nettop/intel/Vision%203D%20Series/) mini PC.

It does not have anything denoting polarity on the outside of the device itself. And from what I can find, it does not tell you on the product page or [the manual](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/Vision%203D%20Series.pdf) either.

I don't have the original power unit.
I started taking the device apart to look for something that would tell me, but it looks a bit daunting.
If nobody can help me determine the polarity from what I have provided, what should I look for when taking the device apart? Do I try and find the port from the inside of the device? Do I look somewhere else?
Update: I called Asrock support and they did not have information about the dc polarity either. They suggested I email them so I have done so. Waiting for a response

Comment: With a good ohmmeter see what the outside power shell is connected to.  Usually, not always, and make ZERO assumptions, outside shell is negative. Center conductor is positive. Ask Asrock support.

Comment: Through their webpage, find a dealer in your country and get an ORIGINAL power supply.